# Ignoring Healthchecks With Graylog-Collector

Tags: logging, centralized-logging

I have a log file with a mix of health checks and actual hits in it. I'd like to collect all the logs except the /healthcheck hits. Can graylog-collector handle this for me?

I've read through the documentation [here](http://docs.graylog.org/en/1.3/pages/collector.html), but I don't see anything relevant to my question. Is anyone else doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collectors just ship the log file or event log source.

What you can do is build streams to match your criteria. It can be sent to various outputs or alerted on.

And because you have both, you can know the request rate, and if the load balancer stops doing health checks.

Comment: Good point about keeping tabs on the health check.